# "Google Speech to Text" does not give accurate results when used for login or registration

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

In my android app i want user to be logged in through voice but google speech to text always gives wrong result.

[image]

Comment: Why would you have your user say the password out loud?

Comment: Yeah i was wrong,will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition is still very new tech, and it isn't advanced enough to understand the difference in terms of when to convert the word `dot` into `.` vs the String literal `dot`.

In addition, depending on the surroundings (background noise), pronunciation, accent and a lot of other language-related variables, there's a chance it'll misinterpret what you say. The `dot`->(`.`|`dot`) is just one example of that.
The same applies with emails, because when you say `dot`, there's a high chance it'll interpret that directly, instead of thinking of it as a character. There's the same with `@` and other non-letter characters.

---

Besides, as [Twometer said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406901/google-speech-to-text-does-not-give-accurate-results-when-used-for-login-or-re#comment83802734_48406901), using speech-to-text for login is not a good idea, considering security problems.

Comment: Thanks Zoe.I think i need to use something else.